# Bootcov in rms package not working when cluster variable included in regression as fixed effect

Tags: r, regression, rms, hmisc

I'm trying to use `bootcov` to get clustered standard errors for a regression analysis on panel data. In the analysis, I'm including the cluster variable as a fixed effect to address cluster-level confounding. However, including the cluster variable as a fixed effect causes `bootcov` to throw an error ("Warning message:...fit failure in 200 resamples. Might try increasing maxit"). I imagine this is because the coefficient matrix varies over bootstrap replications depending on which clusters are selected ([here's a similar issue and solution in Stata](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1440808-best-practice-for-cluster-bootstrapping-with-fixed-effects)).

Does anyone know a way around this problem? If not, I can try to manually edit the function myself. Unfortunately, I can't use the cluster option in `robcov` because my analysis actually requires the `Glm` function rather than the ols function. Furthermore, I want to stick with the `rms` package because my analysis involves restricted cubic splines, which `rms` makes easy to visualize, and test via ANOVA (although I'm open to other suggestions).

Thanks for the help. I copied an example below.

```
#load package 
library(rms)

#make df
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- sample(c(1:100),1000, replace=TRUE)
z <- factor(rep(1:50, 20))
df <- data.frame(y,x,z)

#set datadist
dd <- datadist(df)
options(datadist='dd')

#works when cluster variable isn't included as fixed effect in regression
reg  <- ols(x ~ y, df, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
reg_clus <- bootcov(reg, df$z)
summary(reg_clus)

#doesn't work when cluster variable included as fixed effect in regression
reg2  <- ols(x ~ y + z, df, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
reg_clus2 <- bootcov(reg2, df$z)
summary(reg_clus2)
```

Comment: You have a choice: You can use regression methods to account for the clustering effects parametrically OR you can use `bootcov` to account for them non-parametrically. Doing both just confuses things. If you don't believe me, and why should you, then post a similar question on CrossValidated.com. I think Frank Harrell reads those question more assiduously.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try posting on CrossValidated. However, in economics, I often see models run on state-level panel data where the authors include state and year fixed effects and cluster their standard errors at the state level, which is what I'm hoping to do.  You think those models are incorrect?

Comment: Or, in that scenario, is adjusting one's standard errors for clustering using robcov-style cluster-robust standard errors correct (and more common), while adjusting one's standard errors for clustering using a cluster bootstrap incorrect?

Comment: One option would be to program the cluster bootstrap myself and run Glm within each bootstrap repitition. The code below works, although I’m sure it could be done faster using data.table. This doesn’t solve the ANOVA problem though, and doesn't yet work with `contrast`. 

`boot <- replicate(100, {
  cluster_sample <- data.frame(z = sample(df$z, replace = TRUE, 50))
  dat_sample <- df %>% inner_join(cluster_sample, by = 'z')
  Glm(x ~ rcs(y, 4) + z, data = dat_sample)$coefficients[2:4]
})`